# match values from a dataframe with values in another datframe of different length based on two variables in R

Tags: r, merge, r-markdown, match

I have 2 very large dataframes. Here's a simplified example:

```
# FIRST
ID <- c(1,22,33,4,4)
SIC <- c("300", "300", "120", "250", "250")
fyear <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, SIC, fyear)

ID  SIC fyear
1   300 2000        
22  300 2000        
33  120 2000        
4   250 2000        
4   250 2001        

#SECOND
SIC <- c("300","120", "250", "250")
fyear <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001)
count <- c(7,5,8,2)

df2 <- data.frame(SIC, fyear, count)

SIC fyear count
300 2000    7       
120 2000    5       
250 2000    8       
250 2001    2
```

I need to adda a column in df1 with the values from count in df2 and to do this I need to match by both SIC and fyear. The desired output is:

```
ID  SIC fyear count
1   300 2000    7   
22  300 2000    7   
33  120 2000    5   
4   250 2000    8   
4   250 2001    2
```

I already tried with merge by SIC and fyear but the results are incorrect. I looked around for an answer but I can't seem to get one that can help me solve this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for `dplyr::left_join()`

```
left_join(df1, df2, by=c("SIC","fyear"))
  ID SIC fyear count
1  1 300  2000     7
2 22 300  2000     7
3 33 120  2000     5
4  4 250  2000     8
5  4 250  2001     2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel kinda stupid for having asked such a silly question. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikaDalCortivo There are no stupid questions, consider accepting the answer if it worked for you :)